# one vs. two completion blocks

Tags: ios, macos, objective-c-blocks, nserror

I'm using a [network kit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) that uses the `twoBlock` approach, but I prefer using the `oneBlock` in my own code. Which makes me confused if the `twoBlock` approach is better. Somehow I don't see it.

Is there any way that one approach is better than the other approach?

---

**oneBlock approach**

1 block that combines data and error:

```
-(void)oneBlock {
    [self startWithCompletionBlock:^(id obj, NSError* error) {
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"success: %@", obj);
        }
    }];
}
```

---

**twoBlock approach**

2 blocks that is dedicated to handling data and error:

```
-(void)twoBlocks {
    [self startWithCompletionBlock:^(id obj) {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", obj);
    } errorBlock:^(NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can say that either one is better. There is simply a different balance of pros and cons.

The main advantage of the two blocks approach is that you get a better separation of code for the "happy" path and code for error management. (This separation sounds similar to one of the advantages offered by the use of exceptions, but is a different beast; indeed, catch blocks allow to collect in one place, i.e., outside of your "functional" block, all the code to manage a bunch of possible error conditions that may arise within the "functional" block and whose management would be normally scattered all over it; in the 2-blocks example above, there is none of this, since the code to manage the error condition still appears intermixed with the rest of the code of your function).

On the other hand, it may well happen that in both cases, i.e., success and failures, you would like to take some common action. Think of, e.g., serializing a bunch of network operation: when one operation completes, you execute the next, both when the former operation was completed with success or failure. This is clearly a case where you will have some replication of code if using the 2-block approach.

Overall, I don't believe there is a great deal of a difference, since you can easily do what you need to do with both approaches, but in specific cases, one approach can fit your workflow better than the other.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

I find the 2 block approach "cleaner". You don't need that if/else block, so there's better separation of error handling. It's also 1 line less. Not a huge difference overall, but it helps keep the code that little bit tidier and easier to read, that's all.

The other thing I think makes the 2-block better is that the error handling is automatically pushed to the end. I prefer code to be in the "Do all of this stuff, except if something goes wrong" form to the "assume something went wrong! It didn't? Oh, carry on." style. Maybe I'm an optimist. Either way, I'd rather see the important stuff at the top, and the error handling out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer #1. I think it should be up to the client code to decide what the actual error is and what it means in the current context, based on the NSError instance being sent back.

In option #2, if the completion block contains more than just a few lines of code, which is likely if used in a view controller for example, there is a big chance you want to execute a lot of the same completion code in the two blocks regardless of if an error occurred or not (Updating the UI, restoring some state etc). This would result in unnecessary code duplication.

Also, option #1 is less code if you happen to not care about the error case.

Answer (score 1):

I've settled on the two-block approach. The advantages are:

- It allows for returning an object and an error, in case that is ever needed
- No question of ordering or whether one or both can ever be called
- If you ever add a third variable to another call-back, things are much less messy

In my mind multiple blocks should be reserved for multiple, sequential call-backs. Think of the way UIView animation works.

Comment: two-block approach... don't you mean the one-block approach?

Answer (score 1):

For the reason @sergio mentions, I think the oneBlock approach is cleaner. It gives the caller more flexibility to manage the code paths. With callback APIs like this, there is frequently cleanup (or next step) code that must be called at the end of the callback, whether it's successful or not:

```
-(void)oneBlock {
    [self startWithCompletionBlock:^(id obj, NSError* error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"success: %@", obj);
        }
        self.connection = nil;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateUI];
        });
    }];
}
```

Also, if the success block is long, twoBlocks just reads poorly:

```
-(void)twoBlocks {
    [self startWithCompletionBlock:^(id obj) {
        [self doSomething];
        [self doSomethingElse];

        [self setUpSomeOtherRequestWithCompletionBlock:^(id obj) {
            [self doSomething];
            [self doSomethingElse];

            NSLog(@"inside request succeeded");
        } errorBlock:^(NSError* error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateUI];
        });
    } errorBlock:^(NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```